# PDF of Sum of $\chi^2$ and Normal Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am interested in calculating the p.d.f of the random variable

$$
Y = a + b^\intercal z + c \|z\|_2^2,
$$
where $a,c$ are constants, $b \in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ is a standard normal distribution, where $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$. 
It is known that the norm squared of a standard normal distribution is a $\chi^2$ distribution, which has p.d.f

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}z^{n/2 - 1} e^{-z/2},
$$
and $b^\intercal z$ is a normal distribution such that $b^\intercal z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,b^\intercal b)$. I can always rewrite this in terms of a standard normal distribution as $b^\intercal z = \sqrt{b^\intercal b} \ \tilde{z} = \|b\|_2 \ \tilde{z}$, where $\tilde{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is a standard normal random variable (scalar). 
This then gives

$$
Y = a + \|b\|_2 \tilde{z} + c \|z\|_2^2,
$$
which is the sum of a standard normal random variable and $\chi^2$ random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom.
My question is what would be the p.d.f of $Y$, i.e., what is the p.d.f of the sum of a $\chi^2$ distribution and a standard normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete the square to write $Y=a+b^Tz+c\|z\|^2$ in the form
$$\begin{align*}\frac{Y-a}c&=\frac{b^Tz}c  +\|z\|^2\\
&=\|z+\frac{b}{2c}\|^2-\frac{\|b\|^2}{4c}\\&=\|z+\mu\|^2-\frac{\|b\|^2}{4c}
\end{align*}$$
where $\mu=b/2c.$
By rotational invariance of $N(0,I_n)$ we may assume $\mu=(m,0,0,\ldots,0)$, so $\|z+\mu\|^2=(z_1+m)^2+z_2^2+\cdots+z_n^2$, which has the well-known [noncentral chi squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).
The density of $Y$ is thus obtainable from the noncentral chi-squared density by an affine transformation of variables.

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by rotational invariance of the standard normal? How can we write $\mu = b/2c = (m,0,\ldots,0)$?

Comment: The vector $z\sim N(0,I_n)$ has the same distribution as the vector $w=Rz$, when the matrix $R$ is orthogonal, that is, obeys $R^TR=I_n$.  Because  the joint density function of $z$ actually only depends on $\|z\|^2$.  As for the $\mu$ and $m$ claim: for any 2 unit vectors, there is an orthogonal matrix mapping the one to the other.